# Custom DB in joomla based website

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, integration

I usually code in plain PHP/MySQL and have very little experience working with CMSs. I have taken up some task for our organization whose website is joomla based.

I want to create a form, whose submitted input will be stored in a DB. How can I integrate my module (plain PHP files and MySQL Database) with the joomla based website?

Comment: It may be helpful to specify, which version of Joomla is being used.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tuturials for creation extentions to joomla
Here are offcial ones.
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1
...etc
Also lots of 'custom' lessons.
By the way, there are many finished extentions for this cms including free ones 
http://extensions.joomla.org/.  I used this http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/2265 to integrate form into site. Data store in the database and visible inthe admin part of the component. So, maybe I don't need to create your own module/component for your purposes.